# using listagg multiple times to write away ouput

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The first update I do does show the output but as soon as the second update is done it shows nothing, I am not sure how to solve this?

```
 declare
 v_ids varchar2(4000); 
v_ids2 varchar2(4000);
begin

select listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group (order by 
tl.limit_template) into v_ids
  from base_timeline_section bbts,
       base_timeline_org     bts,
       trmt_timeline         tl
 where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
   and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
   and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720';

update time_line tl
   set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
 where tl.limit_template IN (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_ids, '[^,]+', 1, 
level) 
                               from (select rownum from dual ) 
                            connect by level <= 
   length(regexp_replace(v_ids,'[^,]*'))+1);


 dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178');

select listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group (order by 
tl.limit_template) into v_ids2
  from base_timeline_section bbts,
       base_timeline_org     bts,
       trmt_timeline         tl
 where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
   and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
   and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '111';

update time_line tl
   set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
 where tl.limit_template IN (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_ids2, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
                               from (select rownum from dual ) 
                            connect by level <= 
 length(regexp_replace(v_ids2,'[^,]*'))+1);


 dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids2 || ' to LIM0178');
end;
```

Updated IDs Table1: 13008,13069,13130,13402,13467,13532,13597,13597,13662,13727,13792,13857,13922,13987,14052,14117,14182,14247,14377,14442,14507,14572,14637,14702,14767,14897,14962,15027,15092,15157,15222,15287,15352,15417,15482,15547,15612,16262,16522,16717,16782 to LIM0178
Updated IDs Table2:  to LIM0178

Comment: check the order among update and select statements. I suppose the second select stmt. should come after the second update stmt.

Comment: I think your second SELECT query returns nothing. have you checked your second query output by executing it as an individual SQL?

Comment: Has nothing todo with your current problem, but why are you using csv for your procedure? You could make the variables of type `sys.odciVarchar2list`, then `select tl.limit_template bulk collect into v_ids` and finally `forall` to make the update, that way you don't have do deal with nasty csv-operations.

Comment: Also, there is no need to store the intermediate result into a variable, you can directly use the `SELECT` query in your `update statement` (`WHERE` clause)

Comment: so my select does bring back a record, it just for some reason does not store the variable

Comment: The strange thing is when I test the second update separately it does update. Updated IDs: 13467 to LIM0178  . I'm not sure why in the query above it does not store anything in the variable when the second select is run?

Comment: The ID 13467 is also part of your first update, so it is already updated when you perform your second query. Perhaps some of your queried data is a view on `time_line` and therefore the condition is not met anymore.

Comment: Even if m second update references a completely different table it still does not set the variable, the variable stays empty, it seems like it only ever sets the variable on the first update and that's what I am trying to solve.